# Use _.filter on object created by _.indexBy

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I started off with an array of objects and used _.filter to filter down on some search criteria and _.findWhere to select out asingle object based on ID.

Unfortunately the amount of data has increased so much so that it's much more efficient to use _.indexBy to index by ID so I can just do data[ID] = id for the _.findWhere's.

However I am stumped on how to replace the _.filter method without looping through all the keys in data.

Is there a better way?!

Edit

The IDs are always unique.
I can't show any real data as it is sensitive but the structure is

```
data = {
    1: {id: 1, name: 'data1', date: 20/1/2016}
    2: {id: 2, name: 'data2', date: 21/1/2016},
    3: {....
}
```

and I need to something like:

```
var recentData = _.filter(data, function(d){d.date > 1/1/2016});
```

To get an array of data or ids.

(n.b. the dates are all in epoch times)

Comment: Is id unique throw the whole array of objects? Then you don't need to filter twice. If not, could you provide some code? For now, I can only advise you to sort the array by some criteria (maybe by ID), keep it always sorted, so that when you need to find something in it, it would be much faster (say, with binary search).

Answer (score 0):

This is really an optimization question, rather than simply which function to use.

One thing to go about this would be if we could rely on sort order of the whole collection. If it's already sorted, you go with something like binary search to find the border elements of your date range and then splice everything from this point. (side note: array would probably work better for this).

If the array is not sorted you could also consider sorting it first on your end  - but that makes sense only if you need to retrieve such information several times from the same dataset.

But if all you got is just the data, unsorted and you need to pick all elements starting from a certain date - no other way that iterate through it all with something like _.filter().

Alternatively you could revert back to the source of your data and check whether you can improve the results that way - if you're using some kind of API, maybe there are extra params for sorting or narrowing down the date selection (generally speaking database engines are really efficient at what you're trying to do)? Or if you're using a huge static JSON as the source - maybe consider improving that source object with sort order?

Just some ideas. Hard to give you the best resolution without knowing all the story behind what you're trying to do.

Comment: The data is essentially static JSON sent from the database but is central to every operation on the page so that sending off ajax requests all the time gets really slow. They are ordered differently depending on who is looking at them. I can order the main set  and then order it differently when rendering but that also seems unefficient

Comment: There's still not enough info to go about. How big is the data set, what kind of other data is there, what's relevant in each scenario, etc. There's lots of variables to take into account. There is one other thing that could be an issue here thou - you mentioned that you primarily compare dates. This may be actually a quite expensive operation (performance-wise). Make sure that when you compare dates you don't actually parse any strings for dates. Either compare unix timestamp or yyyy-mm-dd strings directly without parsing. That might save you here. How many records are there anyway?

Comment: We use epoch times (as stated in the edit) so do not compare date strings, I just used that as short hand. Currently there are 132000 entries.